# Convert CSV curl response to json

Tags: php, json, csv, curl

Im trying to convert a CSV response to JSON but it outputs all the headers first and then all the data so they're disconnected. How can i output it so the headers are against the data?

I need to be able to cycle through each merchant and output 'clicks' for example.

Currently im doing:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'URLHERE,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ));
    
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $res));
    print json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
[
  [
   "Report Name",
   "Sales and Activity Report"
  ],
[
  "Date Run",
  "6/8/23"
],
[
  "Filters",
  "Transaction Date >= 6/1/23",
  "Transaction Date <= 6/8/23",
  "Network ID IN 1",
  "Time Zone = GMT"
],
[
  null
],
[
  "ID",
  "Name",
  "Impressions",
  "Clicks",
  "Click Through Rate",
  "Sales",
],
[
  "3184",
  "website.com",
  "0",
  "19,146",
  "0",
  "8,100",
],
```

Original sample data returned from API:

```
Report Name,Sales and Activity Report
Date Run,6/8/23
Filters,Transaction Date >= 6/1/23,Transaction Date <= 6/8/23,Network ID IN 1,Time Zone = GMT

ID,Advertiser Name,Impressions,Clicks,Click Through Rate,Sales
3184,"website.com",0,"19,146",0,"8,100"
```

Comment: Provide sample CSV data, and expected JSON output please, so it's 100% clear.

Comment: @ADyson have attached the output and explanation for what im trying to do.

Comment: We need the csv sample data too as i mentioned, otherwise we don't know what we're trying to convert it from exactly. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson Ive added what is returned directly from the API call before trying to convert, hope thats right. Thanks

Comment: And what part of this data do you actually need? The first three lines appear to contain "meta" information only, I am guessing it is only the second part you are interested in? If so, explode this at a double line break first, and then parse only the second part of it as CSV.

Comment: Looks like you want to get the header bits first and put them in the first part of your PHP array, so you'll need to parse those separately, and then treat the rest of it as a second dataset, effectively.